# PHP: Permission based Array Items

Tags: php, arrays, permissions

This may be a very basic or stupid question, but I have tried to find the answer here and on google but with no luck. May be I don't know the exact term.

I am creating a function for navigation where by defining array as below

```
array(
    'home' => array(
                "dashboard",
                "analytics"
            ),
    'settings' => array(
                'site',
                'url',
                'etc'
            ),
    'pages' => "pages"
);
```

So now here what I want to do is allow different menu item based on user group. So for instance if Admin than he will be able to access all menu item but if it is moderator than only `home` and `pages` etc..

Thanks a lot for your help

**EDIT------------------------------**

I have different group store into the database. For nor you can consider it from Id 1 to ID 11

What exactly I am looking is to give menu access according to the group within the menu array item. So for instance

if ID is 1 than it will have entire array access.
If ID is 4 than only home and children + page and childrens access

I hope this would help to understand what I am looking..

Comment: If you give negative vote than just put your effort to describe why you gave it. Also if I would be an expert than no need to post a question here :) because I already have an answer. Thanks for your negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply expand your array with a parameter containing the minimum access level, such as:

```
array(
  array("name" => "dashboard", "accesslevel" => 0),
  array("name" => "analytics", "accesslevel" => 2)
),
...
```

When you iterate over the array while creating your menu, you simply ask whether the accesslevel of the user is high enough to have the menu item printed.

```
if (menuItem[accesslevel] <= userAccessLevel) {
  // echo menuItem
}
```

Just my two cents...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I may missed something to explain more..please refer my edited question after few minutes.. thanks a lot

Comment: hey @pixelngrain - i guess you will have to store the accesslevel in the database for each user. Then you can proceed the same way as i have described. Good Luck!

Comment: But I am storing user in group and I want accessibility based on group not based on user. So still I need to store user level? Can't it done on group level?

Comment: Sorry, missed that point! Well, then store the accesslevel in the group and when querying for the user get the accesslevel into the user data via a JOIN statement - how does that sound?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that what you said. Can you please provide me some example? Even I am not sure how to store access level into the group table. Or you are talking about something different?